# How to validate xml so that only elements that actually exist can be used as attributes?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, schema

So, basically what I want to do is to emulate the "ref" attribute of schema validation.  I have the following XML, for example:

```
<node name="parent">
  <subordinate name="child3" />
</node>

<node name="child1" />
<node name="child2" />
```

And I want this to be flagged by my schema as invalid, since "child3" isn't one of the available 'node' options (it wasn't specified).  I have the following schema:

```
<xs:element name="node" nillable="false">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute ref="name" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="subordinate" nillable="false">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute ref="name" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But I'm not sure how to specify that the "subordinate" element's "name" attribute must come from another defined "node" element.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an XSD expert, but I believe you want to declare the name attribute on `node` as an XSD type `ID`, and the name attribute on `subordinate` as an IDREF.

Edit: Added references

ID/IDREF datatypes: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#ID

ID/IDREF validation: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-id